# How Can Read Values from File, store them in a structure and find their average, sum, product etc... using C

Tags: c, struct, file-io

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<windows.h>

#define SIZE 1024

typedef struct rational
{
    int  numerator;
    int denominator;
    struct rational *next;
}rational;

double add_rationals(rational*);
void multiply_rationals();
void subtract_rationals();
void divide_rationals();
void read_data(FILE*, int[], int*);
void display_values(rational*);
rational * createList(int []);

int main()
{
    system("cls");


    FILE* ifp;
    ifp = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    int data[SIZE] ={0};
    int sz = SIZE;
    
    read_data(ifp, data, &sz);
    
    printf("\nRead Integer Count:%d\n", sz);

    rational* HEAD = createList(data);
    display_values(HEAD);
 
    /*
        want to start after the 1st number because 1st number is size of arr
        data[0] is the 1st number we just read from the text
    */

    //display_values(HEAD, data[0]); // passing data[0] as size cuz the 1st number is size


}



// double add_rationals(rational* r)
// {
//     rational* c;
//     c = r;

//     static double x = 0 , y = 0, sum;
//     x = r->numerator;
//     y = r->denominator;

//     while(c->next != NULL)
//     {
//         sum = x/y + add_rationals(r->next);
//     }

//     return sum;
    
// }

rational * createList(int data[])
{
    rational *head = NULL;
    rational *temp = NULL;
    rational *p = NULL;
    rational *r = NULL;
    int count = 0;
    
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
    {
        temp = (rational*)malloc(sizeof(double));
        temp->numerator = data[i];
        temp->denominator = data[++i];
        
        temp->next = NULL;

        if(head == NULL) // Checking if the List has started yet
        {
            count++;
            head = temp;
            printf("\nHEAD NUMERATOR: %d, HEAD DENOMINATOR: %d\n\n", head->numerator, head->denominator);
        }
        else
        {
            p = head;
            while (p->next != NULL)
            {
                count++;
                p = p->next;

            }
            p->next = temp;
            
        }
        
    }
}




void display_values(rational* HEAD)
{
    rational* o = NULL;
    o = HEAD;
    while(o->next != NULL)
    {
        printf("\n\nNUM: %d, DEN: %d", o->numerator, o->denominator);
        o = o->next;
    }
    
}

void read_data(FILE* fptr, int d[], int*size)
{
    *size = 0;
    while ((fscanf(fptr, "%d", &d[*size])) == 1)
        (*size)++;
    
}
```

PROBLEMS>>>

1. I am unable to display all the elements from the linked list in the function `void display_values()` function
2. The pre-requisites are like this .. take the 1st number from a text file and create an array of that size...
   Let me show you with example:
   2 5 2 6 7 being the integers in the text file

I want to read the 2nd and 4th items to a struct as numerators and the 3rd and 5th as denominators
I want 5/2 and 6/7 as rationals and do all these operations with them
Like Add, Sub, Mul , Div...etc

Comment: Looks like the first data in in your input file example 2, is the pairs of numerator and denominator. Also are you sure if your _data_ variable with _data_ is getting passed into create list function.   Also take a look at this example [Given a linked list which is sorted, how will you insert in sorted way](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-a-linked-list-which-is-sorted-how-will-you-insert-in-sorted-way/)

Comment: Including conio.h and windows.h restricts your code to a Windows platform while you do not use them. Please try to only include relevant headers.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I included windows.h to use the system("cls"); function to clear my internal terminal upon execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making it much too complex.

You should:

1. read a single integer from the input file
2. allocate an array of that number of rational struct
3. loop that number of times reading one struct and making it point to the next in the array
4. make next=NULL for the last element of the array

That way, you use one single malloc, and avoid the `data` integer array.

Possible code:

```
...
rational* read_data(FILE*, int*);
...
    rational* HEAD = read_data(ifp, &sz);

    printf("\nRead Integer Count:%d\n", sz);

    display_values(HEAD);
...
rational* read_data(FILE* fptr, int* size)
{
     *size = 0;
    if (1 != fscanf(fptr, "%d", size)) return NULL;
    rational* ls = malloc(*size * sizeof(rational)); // never cast return value of malloc!

    for (int i = 0; i < *size; i++) {
        if (2 != fscanf(fptr, "%d%d", &ls[i].numerator, &ls[i].denominator)) {
            free(ls);
            return NULL;
        }
        ls[i].next = ls + i + 1;  // by definition same as &(ls[i+1])
    }
    ls[*size - 1].next = NULL;
    return ls;
}
```

But you should add some error processing for `fopen` returning NULL or `read_data` returning NULL (file read error)...

Comment: In the statement->   rational* ls = malloc(*size * sizeof(rational));    what does   *size   do?  
and another thing. 2 != fscanf(fptr, "%d%d", ...) what does the 2 signify . Thanks for the answer

Comment: Those are too basic C language questions. You cannot fully learn C language from SO questions, but should start with a good tutorial...

Comment: Ok thanks... what tutorial do you recommend

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple problems in your code, I corrected them below in comments:

```c
rational* createList(int data[])
{
    rational *head = NULL;
    rational *temp = NULL;
    rational *p = NULL;
    rational *r = NULL; // this variable is not used
    int count = 0; // I didn't see the purpose of this variable
    
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) // the 5 is a magic number, 
    {                          //if the input file changes, the code will not run as intended
        temp = (rational*)malloc(sizeof(double)); // space should be allocated for rational type not double type
        temp->numerator = data[i];
        temp->denominator = data[++i];
        
        temp->next = NULL;

        if(head == NULL) 
        {
            count++;
            head = temp;
            printf("\nHEAD NUMERATOR: %d, HEAD DENOMINATOR: %d\n\n", head->numerator, head->denominator);
        }
        else
        {
            p = head;
            while (p->next != NULL)
            {
                count++;
                p = p->next;

            }
            p->next = temp;            
        }       
    }
    // the return value for this function is missing.
}

void display_values(rational* HEAD)
{
    rational* o = NULL;
    o = HEAD;
    while(o->next != NULL) // this condition will miss the last node of the linked list
    {
        printf("\n\nNUM: %d, DEN: %d", o->numerator, o->denominator);
        o = o->next;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: My bad it was supposed to return   head   and use that head to iterate through the list

Comment: I used 5 for a test run, sorry I didn't specify that. But How can I implement exactly this.. input is 2 5 4 6 1 lets say... and the 1st number signifies there are 2 rationals which are 5/4 and 6/1. If it was 4 there will be 8 numbers after it. How can I add or subtract them.. Thanks a lot!